# Store the particular element of the grid view as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my code in aspx and c#

The grid view is shown below

```
 FID    Name     

 100    ab  *Download*

 200    bb  *Download*



<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"

 CommandArgument='<%Eval("FID")%>'  Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadFile" />
```

I need to download the information of every individuals in terms of their FID so I am executing the below code but its not returning anything

```
  protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    string FID = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;


    var dt = GetData("select * from Personal_det where FID = '"+ FID +"'");

    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
   //
  // more code
 //
              }
 }
```

But irrespect of FID if I try to execute the code as

```
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    string FID = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;


    var dt = GetData("select * from Personal_det “ );

    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
     //
    // more code
     //
              }
    }
```

This code will download the document what I need for the FID which is stored in session.
So I got to know that the  problems is in the sql query that I have included in the code,As you can see in the above grid view every row has a download link for every FID so I need to get access the FID from grid view and call it in the sql query that I have written in the code

Comment: You are missing a #. It should be `<%#Eval("FID")%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `gridView_RowCommand` event.

```
protected void gridView_RowCommand(object sender, object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
     gridView.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
     if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
     {
          DownloadFile(gridView.DataKeys[rowIndex]["FID"].ToString());
     }
}
```

In your aspx code use DataKeyNames="FID" and your link button should look like

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'  Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadFile" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didnt tried your answer but the error i found out was in the CommandArgument itself,i changed it to  `<%#Eval("FID")%>`

Answer (score 0):

there is missing # in  <%Eval("FID")%>, replace it with <%# Eval("FID")%>

Comment: I cant take it as a integer because FID may be 'm001' which is a string so i need it in string

Comment: I have stored FID as a string in the database